# Equation of a line tangent to circumference

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry

Discover the general equation of the tangent line to the circumference $x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 4y + 1 = 0$ by the point $(3,4)$. **NO CALCULUS**.

> - by the circumference equation i discovered that $C(1, -2)$ and $r=2$
> - with the point $P(3,4)$ I put in the line equation:
>
> > $$(y - yo) = m (x - xo)$$
> >     $$y - 4 = mx - 3m$$ 
> >     $$mx - y + 4 - 3m = 0$$
> >
> > with the equation and the point of the circumference, I put them in the distance between point and line equation:
> >
> > > > > $$\frac{|a x + by + c|} { \sqrt{a² + b²}} = 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\frac{|m + (-2)(-1) + 4 - 3m|}{ \sqrt{(m)² + (-1)²}} = 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\frac{|-2m + 6| }{ \sqrt{m² + 1} }= 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\left(\frac{|-2m + 6| }{\sqrt{m² + 1
> > > > }}\right)^2 = 2^2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$4m² - 24m + 36 = 4m² + 4$$
> > > >
> > > > $$m = \frac{3}{4}$$
> >
> > With this i found the equation: $\frac{3}{4}x - y = 0$

Wolfram graphic: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eohl0i7ciu3

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?  If so,  just use implicit differentiation to find $\frac {dy} {dx}$, then plug in your points to get the slope

Comment: No, i'm not. High school math, not College. Sorry.

Comment: Check,  alas I did high school geometry after calculus (Weird math education history), hopefully someone else will come along who knows how to do this without calc :)

Comment: Ok, i'll wait. Thanks, man.

Comment: Oh, I suggest editting the question also to indicate what level of math you're okay with using/not using.  For example, put in "No calculus".   Is trigonometry okay?

Comment: Please remove the answer from the question body, and the «SOLVED» from the title (we don't do this title thing, as you'll notice if you browse the last 10000 questions! :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - by the circumference equation i discovered that $C(1, -2)$ and $r=2$
> - with the point $P(3,4)$ I put in the line equation:
>
> > $$(y - yo) = m (x - xo)$$
> >     $$y - 4 = mx - 3m$$ 
> >     $$mx - y + 4 - 3m = 0$$
> >
> > with the equation and the point of the circumference, I put them in the distance between point and line equation:
> >
> > > > > $$\frac{|a x + by + c|} { \sqrt{a² + b²}} = 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\frac{|m + (-2)(-1) + 4 - 3m|}{ \sqrt{(m)² + (-1)²}} = 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\frac{|-2m + 6| }{ \sqrt{m² + 1} }= 2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$\left(\frac{|-2m + 6| }{\sqrt{m² + 1
> > > > }}\right)^2 = 2^2$$
> > > >
> > > > $$4m² - 24m + 36 = 4m² + 4$$
> > > >
> > > > $$m = \frac{3}{4}$$
> >
> > With this i found the equation: $\frac{3}{4}x - y = 0$

Wolfram graphic: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eohl0i7ciu3

Comment: Congratuations!

Comment: Rather than adding 'solved' to the question's title, please click the 'accepted' green button next to your answer :)

Comment: I know. Just wainting 48h

Answer (score 3):

Your equation describes a circle of radius two centered at the point $(1,-2)$. A line through a point $(x,y)$ on the circle is tangent to the circle if and only if it is perpendicular to the line from the center to the point $(x,y)$ and this line has slope $(y+2)/(x-1)$.  Thus, you could simultaneously solve the equations
$$\frac{y-4}{x-3}=-\frac{x-1}{y+2} \: \text { and } \: x^2-2 x+y^2+4 y+1=0.$$

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand. sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** ( I am not sure whether you can use vector analysis, if not, see Method 2)

The equation of circle is $(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2=4$. $O=(1,-2), M=(3,4)$ Then points of the circle has form $P=(1+2cos(\theta),-2+2sin(\theta)),\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Then the $OP=(2cos(\theta),2sin(\theta))$, $PM=(-2+2cos(\theta),-6+2sin(\theta))$. Since $OP$ is perpendicular to $PM$, we have $PM \cdot OP=0$, then we get $3sin(\theta )+cos(\theta )=1$. Then combined with $sin^2(\theta )+cos^2(\theta )=1$, we can get two points (the system can be solved easily $\sin(\theta_1)=0, \sin(\theta_2)=\frac{3}{5}$). Then we get two lines.

**Method 2**

We observe $P_1=(3,-2)$ is on the circle, hence one tangent line must be $x=3$. Then the other point $P_2=(x,y)$ must be symmetric w.r.t $P_1$ in terms of line passing through $OM$.

Write down the line $y=x+1$, solve for $P_2$. Using $P_1P_2$ is perpendicular to OM, the middle point of $P_1P_2$ is on line $OM$. (you just need to solve to linear equation, instead of a quadratic equation), you get 
$$ \frac{y+2}{x-3}=-1 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{x+3}{2}+1=\frac{y-2}{2}.$$ Solve for $(x,y)$, we get the other tangent line.